# post_details() got an unexpected keyword argument 'string' in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-urls

urls.py :

```
urlpatterns = [
  path('', views.posts, name='home'),
  path('<string:slug>', views.post_details, name='detail'),
]
```

views.py (function) :

```
def post_details(request, slug):
  posts = Posts.objects.get(pk=slug)
  return render(request, 'posts/post_details.html', {'posts': posts})
```

**NOTE : I am currently learning django.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your parameter is called slug, not string.

```
path('<slug:slug>',...
```

Comment: now I have changed that and its working and also I have changed the `Posts.objects.get(pk=slug)` to `Posts.objects.get(slug=slug)` but now whenever I go to the **admin page** it gives the error `"Posts matching query does not exist."` so what's wrong now?

Comment: This code doesn't have anything to do with the admin site.

Comment: well, thanks anyway, may there is another problem :D @Daniel